# Angular 2 novis getting error TS230

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello i am very new to coding. this is my first attempt to angular 2.

**==my app.ts file==**

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';   
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  

///<reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/> 

@Component({ selector: 'hello-world', template: `<h1>Hello world</h1>` })

class HelloWorld {}                           

bootstrap (HelloWorld);
```

**===and my index.html===**

```
<script src="resources/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script> 
    system.import('app.js')>
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console))</script>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
```

**==while i run tsc app.ts i am getting following error==**

```
C:\Coding\ng-book-2-complete-bookangularjs-2\code\first_app\angular2-reddit-base
>tsc app.ts

node_modules/@angular/core/src/application_ref.d.ts(39,88): error TS2304: Cannot  find name 'Promise'.

node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts(105,123): error TS230 4: Cannot find name 'Map'.

node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(1,25): error TS2304: Canno t find name 'MapConstructor'.

node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(2,25): error TS2304: Canno t find name 'SetConstructor'.

......

node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/collection.d.ts(100,41): error TS2304: Can not find name 'Set'.

...

node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/component_resolver.d.ts(8,53): error TS230 4: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

app.ts(10,7): error TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature tha t is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' opt ion to remove this warning.
```

what mistake i did. please help.

Comment: You don't say what version you're running, but you need to make sure that you install typings.... npm install -g --save typings and then run typings install

Comment: Sorry, I am running below version
NPM v 3.10.3
typescript@2.0.3
Node v6.7.0
typings@1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has solved it. Problem was with my index file. code should be like below.

```
<script src="resources/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script> 
    system.import('app.js')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
```